# Why setInterval does not call anonymous after last iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am just starting out with Javascript/ jquery and trying to make a very basic slideshow. Basically img/slides are absolutely positioned stacked on top of each other inside a container, `z-index` determines the stacking order, set via jquery and then `setInterval` calls an anonymous function every 1.5sec that fades out the top slide to reveal the lower slide.

```js
function slide_play(){
 var slides = $('.slider ul li');
 var no_of_slides = slides.length;

// Set Slides in Order
 for(z=99, i=0; i<no_of_slides; i++) {
  $(slides[i]).css('z-index', z);
  z--;
 }

 var i = 0;
 var first_item  = $(slides[0]);
 var last_item = $(slides[no_of_slides-1]);
  var curr_item  = first_item;

 setInterval(function() {
  $(curr_item).fadeOut('slow');
  if(curr_item.index() != last_item.index()) {
   curr_item = $(slides[++i]);
  } else {
   curr_item = first_item;
  }
 },1500);
}

slide_play();
```

```css
p{margin-bottom: 20px;}

.jumbotron{
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;}

.slider ul {
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 height: 400px;}

.slider ul li{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0 }

img{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100% }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid no-padding">
 <div class="container ">
  <div class="row">

   <div class="col-xs-12 jumbotron">
    <div class="slider">
     <ul>
      <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=250%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" alt="" /></li>
     </ul>
    </div> 
   </div>

  </div><!-- /Row -->
 </div> <!-- /container  -->

</div>
```

The problem is that `setInterval` stops/does not call the anonymous function (which will restart the loop) after the `curr_item` equals to `last_item` (`curr_item = last_item`). Wny?

The problem is that `setInterval` stops/does not call the anonymous function (which will restart the loop) after the `curr_item` equals to `last_item` (`curr_item = last_item`). Wny?

I am just starting out with Javascript/ jquery and trying to make a very basic slideshow. Basically img/slides are absolutely positioned stacked on top of each other inside a container, `z-index` determines the stacking order, set via jquery and then `setInterval` calls an anonymous function every 1.5sec that fades out the top slide to reveal the lower slide.

Comment: Post the relevant code here at SO, if you can create fiddle then sure you can create snippet

Comment: done, pls check

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't keep calling the function? How would you know since the slides have _already faded out_?

Comment: why fiddle link removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slides have already faded out. It is still calling the function, but you can't see the pictures. You need to make them visible again.

You also need to reset `i` to zero.

So if you changed your function to something like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(curr_item).fadeOut('slow');
    if(curr_item.index() != last_item.index()) {
        curr_item = $(slides[++i]);
    } else {
        curr_item = first_item;
        i = 0;
    }
    $(curr_item).show();
},1500);
```

It should work.